# Jasper report error when exporting report to docx

Tags: java, netbeans, jasper-reports, export

I'm trying to export the jasper report to .docx file; but I'm getting this error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint
```

I'm using java to develop this.

*Here is the code I used*

```
public void generateReport2() throws PrinterException {

try {  
String sourceFileName = "src/POS_bill/esFourReport.jasper";
String printFileName = null;
DataBeanFactory2 DataBean = new DataBeanFactory2();
JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanColDataSource = new      JRBeanCollectionDataSource(DataBean.generateCollection());
Map parameters = new HashMap();
printFileName = JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile(
     sourceFileName,
     parameters,
     beanColDataSource);


JRDocxExporter exp=new JRDocxExporter();   
exp.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT,printFileName);
exp.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME,"src/POS_bill/sample_report2.docx");
exp.exportReport();


} catch (Exception e) {

System.out.println(e);
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer!

I removed these two lines

```
exp.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT,printFileName);
exp.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME,"src/POS_bill/sample_report2.docx");
```

and replaced it with these

```
exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(printFileName));
exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput("src/POS_bill/samplereport2.docx"));
```

and now it works finely!